# Talking to someone in anger

Tags: sentence-construction

When someone says something bad to us that we don't like, we in return react calling that person with the same word. How do we say this?

Suppose that someone has said to me, "You are a fool."

Now I am angry and want to say that: It's not me who's a fool but it's you who is a fool.

How should I say this in a dialogue?

A:Hey,you fool.
B: Rather you than me!

A: Hey, you fool.
B: It's you who's a fool.

Is this the right way? If not, how would we say this?

Comment: I'd probably be more inclined to say *a fool calling someone else a fool, eh? That's a common occurrence*.

Comment: It is certainly not the first one. "Rather you than me" is the expression used when someone tells you they intend (or need) to do something which you wouldn't want to do yourself e.g. "I have to speak to a member of my staff about a problem with their body odour" - Reply" "Rather you than me!"

Comment: This isn't a sensible tactic to use in an argument. "You're a fool!" "No, you're a fool", "No you're the fool" "No you are", and so on forever. Don't do this, it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Look who's talking!* and *Speak for yourself!* are two commonly used comebacks meaning "what you're saying applies to you rather than the thing/person you're speaking about". *Pot, meet kettle* is rather less snappy, but can be used as well.

There are also *Takes one to know one!*, *I know you are, but what am I?*, *You can talk!* and a myriad of variants of those with varying degrees of effectiveness as comebacks.

Comment: Using the pot/kettle thing carries the idea that the person being called a fool admits that they are, or may be, which may not be the desired implication.

Comment: No, it means the pot is a black but it call the kettle black which isn’t. So it means you are not a fool.